# How to import a new project in android app properly?

Tags: android, import, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-extensions

I am making an android app which uses google maps api v2. I want to use the clustering features so I am following the tutorial here

http://karnshah8890.blogspot.ca/2013/04/clustering-on-google-map-v2.html

and using the android maps extension plugin

http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/

The problem is how do I import this project in my app. I tried doing file > import, then browse for the folder called `android-maps-extensions` then right click my project folder then click properties then add the reference to the `android-maps-extensions`. Right after that, I get tons of errors in my project about needing to import `R`. If I try that, I get other errors.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I've found a solution:

1. **right-click** on *android-maps-extensions*
2. select "*Android Tools / Add Support Library...*"
3. **right click** on your project
4. in the *Android* section, remove the *google-play-service* library and keep only the *android-maps-extensions*
5. do a clean up, and it should work

Answer (score 0):

try:
New->other->android->Android Project from Existing Code
point to the root dir(android-maps-extensions-1.3.1)
then select android-maps-extensions
[finish]

this is a library project

then you need to add this library to your project:
right click on your project->properties-Android-> scroll to the bottom to the Library section then hit add and select android-maps-extensions.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, and I am getting errors about needing to import R.

Comment: where do you get these error? in your project or the lib project?

Comment: In my java files in the src folder.

Comment: and project->clean doesn't help ?